# $4\times 4$ nilpotent matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar

Tags: matrices

Are there nilpotent $4\times4$ Matrices $A$ and $B$ that are similar?
I cant find a counterexample.
I proved it for $3\times3$ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if we take any invertible matrix $P$ and any $A$ that is nilpotent, then $B=P^{-1} A P$ is also nilpotent. To see this, let $k$ be such that $A^k=0$. Then
$$B^k = P^{-1} AP \times P^{-1}AP \times …= P^{-1}A^k P=0.$$
Thus $B$ is nilpotent as well (and it is easy to see that it has the same degree as $A$). Of course there also exist $A$ and $B$ two different nilpotent matrices that are **not** similar. Just consider $A=0$ and $B\neq 0$ that is nilpotent.

Note that all this holds independently of the dimension of the space.

Comment: Thanks! Are they always similar when they have the same nilpotency index?

Comment: I don't think so. If you consider the two $6\times 6$ bloc matrices, $D_1=\begin{pmatrix} S_3 & 0 \\ 0 & S_3\end{pmatrix}$ and $D_2=\begin{pmatrix} S_2 & 0 \\ 0 & S_3\end{pmatrix}$, where $S_k$ is a shift matrix with degree $k$, both $D_1$ and $D_2$ have degree 3 but I don't think they are similar. For details on shift matrices and the classification of nilpotent matrices, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix#Classification

Comment: (BTW, as you are new: if you are happy with my answer, you can validate it)

Comment: I improved my previous answer: let $D=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and let $A$ and $B$ be the two $4\times 4$ (bloc) matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix} D & 0_2 \\ 0_2 & D\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0_2 & 0_2 \\ 0_2 & D\end{pmatrix}$. Then both $A$ and $B$ have degree (or index) 2 but they are not similar, since rank$(A)=2>$rank(B)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not simillar. There exists an counter-example as...

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},
B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

If $A, B$ are simillar matrix, then there must exists invertible matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$. But note $A^3\ne O, B^3=O$. Thus, $O=POP^{-1}=PB^3P^{-1}=P(P^{-1}AP)^3P^{-1}=PP^{-1}A^3PP^{-1}=IA^3I=A^3$.

This contradicts.

It can be shown by one-sentence as

> $A$ and $B$ has differentminimal polynomial, so they are not simillar.

Comment: I don't think you answer the question.